# Integral with inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Let $p(u,x):=(4 \pi u)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4u}},u>0,x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Let $\mathcal{E}:=\{\phi \in C_c^\infty (\mathbb{R}),\operatorname{supp}(\phi) \subset B(0,1),\|\phi\|_\infty \leq 1\}.$

Prove or disprove that for all $U>0,\beta>0,$ there exist $\epsilon>0,C>0$ such that for all $\lambda \in \left]0,1\right],u,v \in [0,U],$ $$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \sup_{\phi \in \mathcal{E}}\left(\int_0^{|v-u|} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi_x^\lambda(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2) \, dy_1 \right)^2 \,dy_2 \, dr\right)^{1/2}\leq C|v-u|^\varepsilon \lambda^{1/2-\beta},$$
where $\phi_x^\lambda(y) = \lambda^{-1} \phi(\lambda^{-1}(y-x)).$

Comment: The conspicuous typographical difference between $\lambda\in]0,1]$ and $\lambda\in\left]0,1\right]$ results from the use of `\left` and `\right` in `\lambda\in\left]0,1\right]`, so this is another example of why `\left` and `\right` are not only about sizes of delimeters but also about proper horizontal spacing.

Comment: Isn't the integral on the LHS the $L^2$ norm (both in space and time) of  the solution of the heat equation with initial datum $\phi_x^\lambda$? Why do you think it is true?

Comment: Why is it true then? Are you refering to a theorem?

Comment: Call $T=|v-u|$. The integral on the LHS is $\int_0^T \|e^{t \Delta} \phi^\lambda\|_2^2 dt$, where I fixed $x=0$, the $L^2$ norm refers to the space variable and $e^{t \Delta}$ is the heat semigroup with your kernel $p$. If $I_\lambda (\phi)(x)=\phi (x/\lambda)$ then $e^{t \Delta} \phi_\lambda=\lambda^{-1}I_\lambda (e^{t\lambda^2 \Delta} \phi)$  and then its $L^2$ norm coincides with that of $e^{t \lambda^2 \Delta} \phi$ and the initial integral equals $\int_0^T \|e^{t \lambda^2 \Delta} \phi\|_2^2dt$ which tends to $T\|\phi\|_2^2$ when $\lambda \to 0$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439437/integral-with-inequality#comment1133421_439437), in this case `\left` and `\right` are something in the way of distractions; the same effect can be achieved without any sizing using $\lambda \in \mathopen]0, 1\mathclose]$ `\lambda \in \mathopen]0, 1\mathclose]`, and I suspect (but have not checked) that `\left` and `\right` use `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` in addition to their sizing effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\EE{\mathcal E}\newcommand\la\lambda\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$What you wanted us to prove is not true.

Indeed, take any $\phi\in\EE$ such that $\phi\ge1_{[-1/2,1/2]}$. Write $A\gg B$ for $A\ge cB$, where $c$ is a universal positive real constant.

Then, for $w:=x-y_2$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\int_\R \phi_x^\la(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2)\,dy_1 \\ 
    &\gg\frac1\la\,\int_\R dy_1\, 1(|y_1-x|\le\la/2) \frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp-\frac{(y_1-y_2)^2}{4r} \\    
    &=\frac1\la\,\int_\R dz\, 1(|z|\le\la/2) \frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp-\frac{(w+z)^2}{4r} \\    &\ge\frac1\la\,\int_\R dz\, 1(|z|\le\la/2) \frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp-\frac{w^2+z^2}{2r} \\ 
    &\ge\exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{8r}\Big)\frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp-\frac{w^2}{2r}.  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    &\int_\R dy_2\,\Big(\int_\R \phi_x^\la(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2)\,dy_1\Big)^2 \\ 
    &\gg \exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{4r}\Big) 
    \int_\R dw\,\frac1r\,\exp-\frac{w^2}r \\ 
    &\gg \frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{4r}\Big)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and hence
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    I&:=\int_0^{|v-u|}dr\,\int_\R dy_2\,\Big(\int_\R \phi_x^\la(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2)\,dy_1\Big)^2 \\ 
    &\gg \int_0^{|v-u|}dr\,\frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{4r}\Big) \\ 
    &\ge \int_{|v-u|/2}^{|v-u|}dr\,\frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{4r}\Big) \\ 
    &\ge \int_{|v-u|/2}^{|v-u|}dr\,\frac1{\sqrt r}\,\exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{2|v-u|}\Big) \\ 
    &\gg |v-u|^{1/2}\exp\Big(-\frac{\la^2}{2|v-u|}\Big). 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Letting now, for instance, $U=1$, $v=1$, and $u=0$, for all $\la\in(0,1]$ we get
\begin{equation}
    I\gg1. 
\end{equation}
So, if $\beta<1/2$, then there is no real $\ep>0$ and $C>0$ such that $I^{1/2}\le C|v-u|^{\ep} \la^{1/2-\beta}$ for all $\la\in(0,1]$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: What if $\beta>1/2$?

Comment: I think this would work, but I have not checked the details. If you post this version of the question separately and let me know, I will consider it.

Comment: The question is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439814/inequality-and-integral?noredirect=1#comment1134427_439814, after checking computation this version is correct

Comment: Hi, any good ideas for $\beta>1/2$?

Comment: @mathex : I saw the answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/439822/36721 . Are you not satisfied with it?

Comment: It doesn't include details, it seems he's trying to use the fact that $\int_0^ue^{-2\lambda r}r^{-\alpha}dr\leq C \lambda^{\alpha-1}$ for $\alpha=2-2\beta$, hot to use this to deduce the bound?

Comment: @mathex : I suggest you ask the author of that answer for details.